# What's the name of the temperature sensor closest to the PCIe slots in a MacPro5,1?

Tags: hardware, mac-pro, temperature

What's the name of the temperature sensor closest to the PCIe slots in a MacPro5,1?

I'm concerned that an installed PCIe card is overheating.

Answer (score 1):

This is the full list - from iStat Menus

[image]

There isn't really one anywhere near the PCI slots that's also in the same compartment. 
CPU, DIMM & IOH are all in the lower compartment, Drive Bays & PS are in the upper.

I've seen machines reporting a temperature for PCI Slot 1 - but these may have the original graphics cards in them... mine barely has an original anything.